# Removing items from Custom Category - Jumplist

Tags: windows-7, jump-list, taskbar, windows-api-code-pack

How to dynamically remove items from custom category in Jumplist (without deleting the jumplist itself).

Here is how i am creating jumplist and customcategory:

```
// Creating jumplist
list = JumpList.CreateJumpListForIndividualWindow(TaskbarManager.Instance.ApplicationId, windowHandle);

// Creating custom category
userActionsCategory = new JumpListCustomCategory("MyOwnCategory");

// Adding items to custom category
JumpListLink jlapp = new JumpListLink(app_name_path, app_final_name);
jlapp.IconReference = new IconReference(app_name_icon_path, 0);
userActionsCategory.AddJumpListItems(jlapp);

// Adding category to Jumplist
list.AddCustomCategories(userActionsCategory);
```

Now, I wish to dynamically add and **delete** items from this custom category. API code pack seems to provide a mechanism of **only** adding items to category. How can i remove an item from custom category?

Comment: `var list = JumpList.GetJumpList(Application.Current); var newItems = from jumpItem in list.JumpItems
where jumpItem.CustomCategory != "MyOwnCategory"
select jumpItem;
list.Clear(); list.AddRange(newItems); list.Apply();`

Comment: The above is only in System.Windows.Shell namespace which is for WPF not WinForms I believe.